# Can't log in as admin

Tags: 7, users

Someone let us know about an error on our site. I logged in (as an admin). I was able to move the site to maintenance mode and then went through the steps to clear the cache on the site. Once I did that, I am no longer able to log in or even get to the log in page.  I went to our site: safefields.org/user and I get this error: safefields.org is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500  How can I fix any of this if I can't even log in?

Comment: "HTTP ERROR 500" will leave an entry in your webserver error log. Look at that error and it should tell you a lot about what happened. In general, visiting safefields.org/user should allow you to log in a the admin user.

Answer (score 0):

When you type in `safefields.org/user` your site immediately redirects to the login page `safefields.org/user/login` which I believe indicates that your Drupal site is running but gives you a WSOD (white screen of death).
Usually that is because of a memory_limit constraint.

**Things to investigate:**

- Try to use Drush to set the maintenance mode back to 0: `drush vset maintenance_mode 0` this should get your site visible again
- Check your settings.php and see if you have a memory_limit set there, increase to 512M or higher clear cache (either via Drush or empty cache tables directly in the database)
- Check your php.ini file either in the root of your site's folder or in your public_html folder and increase it in size.
- Google "Drupal 7 WSOD" as they say: add error reporting to your settings.php file to see what the errors are so you can search more effectively for what's causing your problem. https://www.drupal.org/node/158043

`error_reporting(-1);`
`$conf['error_level'] = 2;`
`ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);`
`ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);`